# knex.js how to exclude / unselect columns from query

Tags: knex.js

in Knex.js columns like createdAt, updatedAt, createdBy or updatedBy should be excluded from select query(). Invoices table has `id, invoice_date, product_id, qty, rate, amount, createdAt, createdBy, updatedAt, updatedBy` columns. In 90 % of queries I want to exclude the above mentioned 4 columns. Is there is anyway to deselect columns ?

```
 await db('invoices').where('id',4).first();
```

expecting something like to remove columns from select query. I can write required columns name in select() but any alter table need to update its instance. So to avoid I was looking for something like following.

```
 await db('invoices')
.unSelect('createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'createdBy', 'updatedBy')
.where('id',4).first();
```

I found one thread any one know how to implement it [similar solution](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/743)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exclude columns from the results directly in knex but you can remove them after knex returns.

```
const result = db('invoices').where({id: 4}).first();
for (const key in ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'createdBy', 'updatedBy'] {
  delete result[key]
}
return result;
```

If you have a query that returns an array of objects you can use destructuring to remove a set of keys from all elements:

```
const result = db('invoices').where({…some clause});
return result.map(({createdAt, updatedAt, createdBy, updatedBy,...rest}) => rest);
```

Comment: parsing the result set its little bit expensive instead I can write required columns in .select(). I am searching something like  await db('invoices').unselect('createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'createdBy', 'updatedBy').where('id',4).first(); I know its not there we need to write class method enhancement for builder(). So some one has might did this before.

Comment: Some flavors of SQL include an EXCLUDE option for columns and you could do a `.selectRaw()` with that but it really depends on your db. If it's not supported by your underlying db you won't be able to extend knex to support it. Also there is no "parsing" in my answer, just key manipulation. You'd be surprised at how fast it is.